# Angular DataTable not sorting asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables, rxjs

On a datatable that I am using, I am having mixed results when attempting to sort them by using the toggles in the table headers. It appears that columns that get populated by the response in my initial GET call populate and sort as expected. However, the columns with data that comes from the GET calls inside the outer subscription don't sort as expected. Ideally all columns would be able to sort properly.

When wrapping the `this.dtTrigger.next()` in a `setTimeout()` of 5000ms, all columns sorted as expected. So the question here is, how would I wait until the innermost GET call finishes to call the `dtTrigger.next()`so that all of the columns will be sortable once all of the data is finished loading in.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { BuildersService } from '@/services/builders/builders.service';
import { CommunitiesService } from '@/services/communities/communities.service';
import { ContactsService } from '@/services/contacts/contacts.service';

import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

@Component({
  selector: 'datatable-builders',
  templateUrl: './builder-datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./builder-datatable.component.scss']
})
export class BuilderDatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: string = '';
  @Input() showFooter: boolean = true;
  @Input() rowsPerPage: number = 10;
  @Input() viewRoute: string = '';
  @Input() viewText: string = 'View';

  rows = [];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
        private buildersService: BuildersService,
        private communitiesService: CommunitiesService,
        private contactsService: ContactsService
  ) { }

    dataTablesInit() {
        this.dtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
            lengthChange: false,
            info: this.showFooter,
            paging: this.showFooter,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: [4],
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                }
            ],
            initComplete: () => {
                let searchLabels = document.querySelectorAll('.dataTables_filter > label');

                searchLabels.forEach((label) => {
                    label.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Search/Filter Table');
                });
            }
        };
    }

  ngOnInit() {

        this.dataTablesInit();

        // Get the table data
        this.buildersService.getBuilders().subscribe((result: any) => {

            // Get all Rows
            let rows  = result.body.map(row => {

                let communities       = [],
                        communitiesColumn = [],
                        managersColumn    = [];

                        // Get the builders info and set up output
                    row.CommunityIDs.forEach((id) => {
                        this.communitiesService.getCommunity(id).subscribe((result: any) => {
                            communities.push(result.body);
                            communitiesColumn.push( result.body.Name );
                        });
                    });

                    row.Contacts.Managers.forEach((id) => {
                        this.contactsService.getContact(id).subscribe((result: any) => {
                            managersColumn.push(result.body);
                        });
                    });

                    console.log(row);
                    // Set additional row data
                    row.Communities       = communities;
                    row.CommunitiesColumn = communitiesColumn;
                    row.ManagersColumn    = managersColumn;
                    return row;
                });

            this.rows = result.body;
            this.dtTrigger.next();

            console.log(this.rows)
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the synchronicity of JavaScript in general, you can use the keyword Async in the top level GET and Await keyword in the down level GET

e.g :

// Get the table data

```
  async this.buildersService.getBuilders().subscribe((result: any) => {

    ...
    //
     // Get the builders info and set up output

         row.CommunityIDs.forEach((id) => {
                    await    this.communitiesService.getCommunity(id).subscribe((result: any) => {
 ...
    //
      communities.push(result.body);
                            communitiesColumn.push( result.body.Name );
                        });
                    });

                    row.Contacts.Managers.forEach((id) => {
                        this.contactsService.getContact(id).subscribe((result: any) => {
                            managersColumn.push(result.body);
                        });
                    });

                    console.log(row);
                    // Set additional row data
                    row.Communities       = communities;
                    row.CommunitiesColumn = communitiesColumn;
                    row.ManagersColumn    = managersColumn;
                    return row;
                });

            this.rows = result.body;
            this.dtTrigger.next();

            console.log(this.rows)
        });
  }
}
```